# Can't use node-api by worker_threads in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I tried to use two workers to query a container list, but it failed with the error message.It seems that api can't work on the multithreading.

```
FATAL ERROR: HandleScope::HandleScope Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place
 1: 0xb14d40 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa31e30 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xcfb67a v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: 0xcfcedc v8::EscapableHandleScope::EscapableHandleScope(v8::Isolate*) [node]
 5: 0xacc766 napi_open_escapable_handle_scope [node]
 6: 0x7ff67ed6c06f griddb::StoreFactory::getInstance(Napi::CallbackInfo const&) [/home/a/nodejs-api/node-api/griddb.node]
 7: 0x7ff67ed749af Napi::ObjectWrap<griddb::StoreFactory>::StaticMethodCallbackWrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) [/home/a/nodejs-api/node-api/griddb.node]
 8: 0xac44af  [node]
 9: 0xd627db  [node]
10: 0xd63c7c  [node]
11: 0xd642f6 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x1611ad9  [node]
```

Comment: ```StoreFactory::getInstance()``` is not designed to be used in a multi-threaded environment, you should create a separate ```Store``` for each thread. See [issue](https://github.com/griddb/node-api/issues/3).